# Change Bash variable via Perl

Tags: perl, bash, command-line

I would like to use a one line Perl command to change data in a Bash variable.  I think the problem is that the Perl one liner isn't receiving the piped in data.

I know about the bash change variable 
i.e. `findString=${findString//\//\\/}`

I'm curious about getting Perl to work too.  I do not know Perl so keep it simple.

To be clear, these two lines are not working:
I would like the tabs in the text to be changed to \t.  I would like any Unix line ends to be changed to \n.

```
findString=$(cat "${findString}" | perl -0777pe 's/\t/\\t/g')

findString=$(cat "${findString}" | perl -0777pe 's/\n/\\n/g')
```

Here is my bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#The idea here is to change tab to \n
# and line End to \n

# debug info
export PS4='+(${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}):'

# trace all the lines
#set -o xtrace
echo "---------------------- start ----------------------------------------"



# string to change.
# chops off the last \n

read -d '' findString <<"EOFEOFEOF"
# Usage: /Users/mac/Sites/bithoist/commandLine/BitHoist/BitHoist-PPC-MacOS-X [options] input... < input > output
               # Options and inputs may be intermixed
    -stdin     # Use standard input as input file
    -offset nn # Offset next input file data by nn

EOFEOFEOF

findString=$(cat "${findString}" | perl -0777pe 's/\t/\\t/g')

findString=$(cat "${findString}" | perl -0777pe 's/\n/\\n/g')

echo "------------> findString of length ${#findString} is:"
echo -E "${findString}"
echo
```

Comment: You want `echo`, not `cat`, in those commands.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, chepner.  I need echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work.

Here's how

```
$ echo Helloabtb | perl -0777pe 's/a/x/g'
Helloxbtb
$ myvar=`echo Helloabtb | perl -0777pe 's/a/x/g'`
$ echo $myvar
Helloxbtb
```

So if it works with `echo` it should work with `cat`. I suggest using backticks as shown above in my example, and try. Something like

```
 findString=`cat $findString | perl -0777pe 's/\t/\\t/g'`
```

also in most probability, `cat` expects a file. So in your case `echo` might be suited as

```
findString=`echo $findString | perl -0777pe 's/\t/\\t/g'`
```

OR

```
findString=$(echo "$findString" | perl -0777pe 's/\t/\\t/g')
```

OR

```
command="echo $findString | perl -0777pe 's/\t/\\t/g'"
findString=eval($command)
```

Comment: Don't advise using backticks for command substitution in place of `$()` which is what the OP used. The latter form is [much preferred](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) over backticks.

Comment: The question was not whether backticks or `$()` works. That was just a suggestion. Its more of a choice than option, both do the same thing. The OP is using a fairly simple command. If it were a complicated nested command, sure `$()` may make the code readable. But for me both are one and the same. For the sake of it I am updating the answer.

Comment: No, both *don't* do the same thing as you seem to recognize. The readability issue includes avoiding the confusion between single quotes and backticks even for simple process substitution. Your statement "I suggest using backticks" is what prompted my comment.

Comment: Yes, thats because I have been using backticks for a long time now and I did not find any practical issues with doing that, hence "my suggestion". But you are welcome to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

as @chepner already pointed out in his comment, you want to use `echo` instead of `cat`. `cat` expects a filename to cat, so it treats `$findString` as a filename.